# Filezilla : error in connecting to amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a simple Amazon ec2 instance with all the default values. I have downloaded the key which the instance gave me. Now I downloaded filezilla and created a new site with my public DNS, port number blank, protocol sftp, some username and password, and clicked ok. Then in the edit-> settings I added my private key downloaded from amazon and clicked connect. Still I get following exception:

Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:  Could not connect to server

Am i going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Have you added the SFTP port to your security configuration?

Comment: Seems like you used the pem file instead of .ppk file.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue can be one among the following

1. You might have used the .pem file instead of .ppk file. Create a ppk
   file with the pem file and try accessing the instance. You can use
   puttygen for converting pem file into ppk.
2. Ensure that port 22 is accessible from your network. Verify the
   security rules present in the security group associated with the ec2
   instance.
3. The instance can be inside a private VPC and you are
   trying to access it outside private VPC.